# How to print the div as it exactly appears in web page in typescript in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to print a div as it in the web page but whenever I click on the print button the elements of the div is getting in a side of the print tab.

Here is my print function below

```
print(): void {
let printContents, popupWin;
printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
popupWin = window.open('', '_blank');
popupWin.document.open();
popupWin.document.write(`
  <html>
    <head>
      <title></title>
      <style>


      </style>
    </head>
<body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
  </html>`
);
popupWin.document.close();
```

}

I heard that I need to use css to solve that. But where should I put that css code? I tried adding the code in the style tag but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it with the Angular InnerHTML directive-binding, use the following code:

```
print(): void {
let printContents, popupWin;
printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
popupWin = window.open('', '_blank');
popupWin.document.open();
popupWin.document.write(`
  <html>
    <head>
      <title></title>
      <style>


      </style>
    </head>
<body onload="window.print();window.close()">
    <div [innerHTML]="printContents"></div>
</body>
  </html>`
);
popupWin.document.close();
```

Comment: I tried your code but the print tab appears empty now. Can you please explain me what " <div [innerHTML]="printContents"></div>" means? I am a noob in ng4.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Which doc? Can you help me out with a link?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation

Comment: AFAIK this is not going to work because your popupWin does not run Angular. Browser itself does not understand Angular's bindings.

Answer (score -2):

You could indeed solve that with css and media queries. 
With each angular component you should have a .css file. You put the css in it.

example css:

```
@media print { 
 /* All your print styles go here */
 #header, #footer, #nav { display: none !important; } 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It makes a false normative claim. It references an abysmal resource. it does not quote that resource.

Comment: I now added a media query example and removed the link. I hope it will be more useful